# Starting a node.js via cron fails silently

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, node.js

I am currently trying to set up a cronjob that will start a node.js server whenever that server is down.

For that purpose, I have written a simple script to test and start the node server.

```
#!/bin/bash

ts=$(date +%T)

if pgrep -f "node"
then
    echo $ts": node running"
else
    echo $ts": node not running"
    '/usr/bin/node' '/home/pi/project/serveronly/index.js' > '/home/pi/project/node.log'
fi
```

The corresponding crontab is:

```
m   h   dom   mon   dow   command
*   *    *     *     *    /home/pi/project/sanity_check.sh >> /home/pi/project/cron.log 2&>1
```

my logging shows the following:
If I simply start the script it will start the server and log the node.js output properly.

For the script started by cron it looks this way:
If an instance of `node.js` is currently running it will detect that and log accordingly.
If none is detected it will log into `cron.log` properly, but it will log nothing into `node.log` and it will not start a server.

Comment: What is the `pwd` inside cron? Please add it to the question body. Why don't you add `cd /` to the script?

Comment: What do you mean by pwd? (as for the cd, I will try that out. It should help me to avoid some mistakes. Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not providing the full path to `/home/pi/project/serveronly/index.js` -- you're missing the initial forward-slash, so the node program is failing to find your script.
2. the command *is* successfully overwriting a file under your home directory, `home/pi/project/node.log`; presumably that's what you meant with `project.log`. If you want to *append* to that log, use two greater-than signs, not one.

I would use this, instead:

```
/usr/bin/node /home/pi/project/serveronly/index.js >> /home/pi/project/node.log
```

Comment: Thank you. this explains the "weird" logging behaviour.  Unfortunately the missing forward-slash is just an error I made while copying. I edited my question accordingly.